# what does structured-block refer to?

Tags: c++, syntax, openmp

I now have seen several times that in an explanation of syntax the phrase *structured-block* was used. For example:

```
#pragma omp single
  structured-block
```

(This is from OpenMP, but that doesn't matter.)

Would the following two lines also count as a structured-block?

```
do_something1;
do_something2;
```

or only the first statement alone?

So, to put it shortly: What do they mean when saying structured-block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation [here](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP3.0-SummarySpec.pdf):

> A “structured  block” is a single statement or a compound statement
>   with a single entry at the top and a single exit at the bottom

Looking up the definition of a compound statement [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/statements):

> A compound statement, or block, is a brace-enclosed sequence of
>   statements and declarations.

Given this definition, `do_something1;` would be the only one part of the structured block as a new "single" statement begins after that. On the other hand if you did

```
#pragma omp <directive>
{
do_something1;
do_something2;
}
```

it would have both in the structured block as its a "compound" statement.

Finally, note the definition stating `single entry at the top and a single exit at the bottom`. This simply means that we should not have an intermediate exit/control-flow breaking point like a `goto` statement, `return` or `throw error` in between.

Comment: A `return` would be a better example than `goto`. (Any code that has a `goto` statement is almost certainly badly written.)

Answer (score 1):

structured-block is either a single statement, like

```
printf("Hello\n");
```

or a sequence of statements enclosed in curly braces:

```
{
    printf("Hello ");
    printf("World\n");
}
```

In addition, OpenMP requires "single entry, single exit", so that means that you cannot have a `goto` or similar branching into the block and that you cannot have a branch leaving the block, e.g. `goto` or in C++ an exception.  Instead, the code needs to reach the closing curly brace.

Comment: A `return` would be a better example than `goto`. (Any code that has a `goto` statement is almost certainly badly written.) Also, it seems strange to qualify part of your answer with "in C++" when the question has C++ as the only language tag.